# How get JSON array with resttemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

API response

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "employee_name": "Tiger Nixon",
            "employee_salary": "320800",
            "employee_age": "61",
            "profile_image": ""
        },
...
]
}
```

public class Data {

```
private int id;

private String employeeName;

private int employeeSalary;

private int employeeAge;

private String profileImage;
```

}

Setter getter and constructor has omitted

public class Employees {

```
private String status;
private Data[] datas;
```

}

```
public Employees getProductList() {
    ResponseEntity<Employees> result = restTemplate.exchange("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees",
            HttpMethod.GET, null, Employees.class);
    return result.getBody();
}
```

And this is returned

Employees{status=success, datas=null}

Why datas is null?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: `data` != `datas`

Comment: Oooooh myyyy  goood! No kidding.  Thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please annotate your fields as `@JsonProperty` and fields names to match input json:

```
public class Data {
    @JsonProperty
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty
    private String employee_name;
    @JsonProperty
    private String employee_salary;
    @JsonProperty
    private String employee_age;
    @JsonProperty
    private String profile_image;
}

public class Employees {
    @JsonProperty
    private String status;
    @JsonProperty
    private List<Data> data;
}
```

Comment: Obviously the `status` field worked without `@JsonProperty`, so the annotations have nothing to do with it.